# How to a hash an array value in c++

Tags: c++, hash

i got a 5x5 matrix and i need to hash its values.

[image]

so i'm trying to hash the 2nd lines and 3rd columns like this

[image]

```
void hashing(int matris[5][5]) {

int x = 0;
int y = 0;

cin >> x;
cin >> y;
for (int i = 0;  i < 5;  i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
    {
        if ((i==x-1)|| (k==y-1))
        {
            matris[i][k] = "*";
            
        }
    }
}
```

}

thats the code but i got a error that follows:

"a value of type "const char*" can not be assigned to an entity of type "int""

does anyone knows how to do it ?

Comment: What are you hoping to do with that statement: _`matris[i][k] = "*";`_? A multiplication operation??

Comment: `"*"` is a null terminated string (a `const char[2]`) and `matris[i][k]` is an `int&`. What are you hoping to do by this assignment?

Comment: You seem to need a matrix of *strings*. Or you should use a special `int` value to mean "print an asterisk" (perhaps `0` or `-1`).

Comment: And a note about what you're doing: It's not *hashing* in the computer-science sense of the term.

Comment: Rather than blurry images, include your input and desired output as text (in a code block so it stays formatted).

Comment: Hashing is related to [hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). You may want to learn how to use [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (to be invoked as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`) with [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/); you should read about [C++ containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)

Comment: My understanding of hashing, is to use a function that takes one or more values and tries to generate a unique value from the data.  IMHO, using a hashing function for a single value is not worthwhile; (just use the value instead, avoid the function).

Answer (score 2):

When you declare `int matrix[5][5]` you are telling your program that you want to store `int`egers in that matrix, basically numbers. So the error says that your can't put into a matrix that stores integers, a char like `"*"`, and infact you can't.

Edit: a possible solutions will be changing your matrix from int to string (parsing integers to strings) as [@Some Programmer Dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) suggested, but that depends on your needs